# convert comma to data in php

Tags: php, arrays

My data is

,asad,rakib,hassan,

I want to convert this into

> asad
> rakib
> hassan

My code is

```
$mark=explode("," , $row['friend_array']);
    foreach ($mark as $row) {
        echo $row;
}
```

Comment: What does this code display and what is different to what you want?

Comment: @NigelRen Hey can you tell me why people are down voting the correct answers and what should we do for it. Have a look at my answer it has been downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your data by unsetting the empty ones in the array as

```
$data = ',asad,rakib,hassan,';
$explode = explode(',', $data);
foreach ($explode as $key => $value) {
 if ($value == null) {
     unset($explode[$key]);
 }
  echo $value.'<br>';
}
```

**Output**

```
asad
rakib
hassan
```

Comment: If this helped you can you please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```php
echo trim(implode(" ", explode(",", ",asad,rakib,hassan,")));
```